# How to get the response of another observable when error occurs?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, observable

I just want to ask if it is possible to get the response of another observable after encountering an error from the another observable?

for example I am calling a two api Avatar and Attachment using a `combineLatest`.

```
val avatar: Observable<ResponseBody> = api().getAvatar()
val attachment: Observable<ResponseBody> = api().getAttachment()

val obs = Observables.combineLatest(avatar, attachment)
        .map { it ->
            if (it.first is Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "getAvatar failed")
            } else {
                updateAvatar()
            }
            if (it.second is Exception) {
                Log.e(TAG, "getAttachment failed")
            } else {
                updateAttachment()
            }

            if (it.first !is Exception && it.second !is Exception) {
                Log.i(TAG, "success first=${it.first}, second=${it.second}")
                updateAll()
            }

        }
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .onErrorReturn { it }
        .subscribe()
disposable.add(obs)
```

I just want to get the avatar response if the attachment error and I want to get the attachment response if the avatar error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, my friend. You can handle error for each observable that you combine by calling [`onErrorReturn()`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#onErrorReturn-rx.functions.Func1-) method. You can use empty ResponseBody for detecting error. Final code

```
val avatar: Observable<Optional<ResponseBody>> = api().getAvatar().onErrorReturn{ Optional.empty }
val attachment: Observable<Optional<ResponseBody>> = api().getAttachment().onErrorReturn{ Optional.empty }

val obs = Observables.combineLatest(avatar, attachment) {avatar, attachment -> 
        if (!avatar.isPresent()) {
            //logic
        }
        if (!attachment.isPresent()) {
            //logic
        }
    }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
     .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
     .onErrorReturn { it }
     .subscribe()
```

If you use java 7 or lower in you project, you can write your own Optional

```
class Optional<T>(val value: T?) {
        companion object {
            fun <T> empty(): Optional<T> = Optional(null)
        }

        fun isPresent() = value != null
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, but the `isPresent` and `empty` is available on Api 24 , my min api is 21, do you have any alternative way to that?

Comment: @dotGitignore, you can use your own wrapper for ResponseBody, that will store data and status. Give me a few minutes to change my solution.

Comment: @dotGitignore, please, mark it as solution if it helps you